# RTL support for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am dynamically adding UIButtons of varying sizes to a horizontal scroll view. These buttons are being laid out from right to left, and I am adjusting the content size accordingly. However when the content size becomes bigger than the size of the scrollview, I'm not able to scroll to the left to see what the rest of the content is, it simply bounces back. I can scroll all the way to the right, but the content there is empty. I want to invert the scrolling direction but I'm not sure how to do that.

What is the appropriate way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're probably still adding the buttons to the left side of your entire content box (the content size is expanded to the right).

In order to support the RTL you're trying to achieve, you ought to keep your scrollview always scrolled to the right when you increase the content size, and move the buttons from their old frames, to the new ones moved towards right as much as you increased the size of the scrollview.

There's a bit of handywork included, so you might want to check into a custom scrollView implementation, either your own, or possibly a library, but I'm not sure if there is one already.